# How to deal with an error in cut --complement command?

Tags: bash, macos, cut

I am facing an error in `cut` command and tried to find a solution but were not helpful. I have a tab-delimited file that I pipe to replace the tabs with comma. Then I pipe to get rid of specific columns using `cut --complement` but I get this error:

```
cut: [-cf] list: illegal list value
```

My command:

```
cat input.txt | grep -v '#' | tr '\t' ',' | cut -d ',' -f2,3,4,5,6 --complement | head
```

When I remove the `--complement` it prints the columns `2,3,4,5,6` but with the `--complement` it does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your version of `cut` support that option? It's a GNU extension; other implementations might not have it.

Comment: it even does not allow me to print ```cut --version```

Comment: You didn't mention what OS you're using, but it does not appear to be one with a GNU userland.

Comment: It is ```Catalina 10.15.4```

Comment: ```GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.```

Comment: the bash version implies nothing about the version of cut

Comment: I am not able to check the cut version, it gives error for ```cut --version```. The error: ```cut: illegal option -- -
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]```

Comment: The problem is with ```--```, otherwise ```cut```works

Comment: @Apex  : You need to install the gnu utilities for this version of  `cut`. What made you think that your `cut` supports `--version` and `--complement`? Didn't you check `man cut` on your machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSD cut doesn't have a `--complement` option. In this specific case, you can use:

```
cut -d , -f 1,7-
```

instead of

```
cut -d ',' -f2,3,4,5,6 --complement
```

Answer (score 0):

Use awk

```
awk '/#/{next}{for(i =2;i<7;i++)$i=$(i+5);NF-=5}1;' FS=\\t OFS=, input.txt
```

(please note: this is my first posting from my phone.  I tested the above using smtx in termux. but...expect cut n paste errors!)